# Image IO error on iOS

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm receiving the following error in the simulator:

```
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData ***
CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData: readSession [0x6b78af0] has bad
readRef [0x6b7a460]
```

I'm using the OpenFlow library. I didn't have any bad experience until now. Now, I don't know why I have this. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PNG's contained some transparent parts and I think this caused the problem, because after removing these parts the error disappeared. Maybe I had some error in my PNG files, because transparency should be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I saw another thread that said these are some Simulator problem. I get them when rendering jpg using an CGImageSource in a thread - which I believe others have noticed too.

Comment: Bad news - getting these (and a crash) when doing the above on an iPad 1 :-(